# Justifying $\sin\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right) = (-1)^n$ without a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you justify this equation without a calculator?

> $$\sin\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right) = (-1)^n$$
>   where "n" is integers greater or equal to 1.

I tried using special triangles and identities, but I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What is $n$? integer?

Comment: I suppose that it is

Comment: I could suppose too but I didn't prefer to suppose.

Comment: Instead of pronouncing $\pi$ as "pi", try pronouncing it as "half-rotation(s)".

Comment: @studentforever  Thanks, forgot to add that in.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus Is this for another bigger question or a question in general? I just remember doing this type of question 2 days ago...

Comment: @dydxx    It's part of one of the solutions given in the Stewart Calculus textbook for chapter 11.5 (alternating series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction.

For $n=0$ one has $\sin{\pi\over 2}=1$

Assume that the identity is valid for $n-1$.

Let's write

$$\sin{\left(n+{1\over 2}\right)\pi}=\sin{\left(\pi+\left(n-1+{1\over 2}\right)\pi\right)}=\sin(\pi+\alpha)$$

with $\alpha=\left(n-1+{1\over 2}\right)\pi$. Now we know that $\forall \alpha,\,\sin(\pi+\alpha)=-\sin{\alpha}$ and therefore

$$\sin{\left(n+{1\over 2}\right)\pi}=-\sin{\left(n-1+{1\over 2}\right)\pi}=-(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^n$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If $n=2m,$  $$\sin\left(2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\sin\dfrac\pi2=(-1)^{2m}$$

What if $n=2m+1$?

---

Alternatively use $\sin(A+B)$

Answer (score 0):

Take the point $P=(1,0)$ in the "$x,y$" plane and rotate it counter-clockwise about the point $(0,0).$ When you have rotated $P$ thru an angle $A,$ the projection of $P$ onto the $y$-axis is  $(\sin A,0)$ because the arc-distance that $P$ has travelled along the circle is $A$. When $(A/\pi)-1/2$ is an integer, the point you have rotated to  is  $(1,0)$ if $n$ is even and is $(-1,0)$ if $n$ is odd ( because $\pi /2$ is one-fourth of the length of the circumference of a circle with radius $1$ .)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the function in the cartesian plane. Look at where the points $(n+1/2)\pi$ lie. They just flip back and forth between the (1,0),(-1,0) points for different values of n.

Comment: That's a good starting point for a proof by, say, induction, but this only proves the property holds for the section of the plane you're looking at.